# How to go Against a Bad Team Setup

Tags: overwatch

**What should someone do if their own team refuses to play in a normal team setup in ranked?**

By 'normal' I mean:

- At least one Tank
- At least one Healer
- Not 3 Snipers
- At least one Offensive

What should someone do if there at least 2 of the above stated things are missing?

I am currently Ranked Gold, mostly because of leavers (5 Matches where I lost because of one or 2 players on my own team left), and I am descending (2437 after Ranked, 2082 now).
Every Loss I take happened when players left or 2 of the above points were missing. I took then one of them as best as I could (mostly I choose my Character as first or second so I must go back to the base and switch them)

Most Overwatch Players play a 2-2-2 setup which is as far as I can see the best thing to do by default, so the things I stated above are a very low expectation.

Comment: 2 Things: i know this question seems like a flame but 80% of my matches that is the reason we loose and that is killing the fun in the game.
Second: when downvoted, please say what i could yo that my question seems better

Comment: I dont think there are any rules about composition but I could be wrong. Did you mean 2-2-2? I think that perhaps it's more to do with countering than compositions, but perhaps even documented counters dont matter if you face opponents that aren't as "good" as you. Maybe you were just unlucky that time you lost that game. I've seen winners that dont meet the criteria you've outlined. Please explain why you choose that criteria as normal. Sometimes the other team is just better than your team. Team composition isn't going to make you win, it can help.

Comment: I play solo all the time. I play with random strangers constantly, I prefer not to group up and play with the same people. I've noticed that more often than not, the games I lose are the ones where someone complains about the hero that someone else has chosen. There's a lot to be said about believing in your team. If there's someone in the team who undermines the  others, chips away at the confidence that they have, then they are likely to fail. Specially if they spend the whole game complaining about someones choice, instead of aiming their anger at the other team.

Comment: Yes i meand 2-2-2. I think that is the best setup to start and then switch to the current needs. And Yes the Team composition is not going to make it a win, but it can easly make a loose.
And Yes, if the Flame-Train is departed, most of the games are lost, and a neutral person can't do anything about it

Comment: @Serverfrog: If nothing else, I suspect that you're getting downvotes because it's a question that has two non-answers - a) carry the team, or b) it varies because you're not playing with the same people every time, and the 'answer' will be different every time. Because this is a Q&A site, and this is a question without an easy answer... I think it falls under [these criteria](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: If you took Overwatch out of the question it pretty much applies to any team-based online game. If you end up with a bad team then you are likely to lose. Sometimes the game helps you out (e.g. TF2 putting limits on classes so you don't end up with 10 engineers, or being matched with people of similar skill), but most of the time you just got to get through the game and hope the next one has a better line up. I'm not sure about Overwatch, but on some games I just pick certain times of the day to play knowing it won't be filled with 12 year olds having their 1 hour a day play on dad's computer.

Comment: You can't really define "normal" in the definition u gave in games such as Overwatch.

Comment: @D.Va Alternate explanation: you lose games where people complain about bad hero choices because people only complain about bad hero choices when they occur, and bad hero choices lead to losses.

Comment: @DCShannon For example, on a team of randoms, hollywood on defence, someone picks symmetra, someone complains about it constantly we lose, now maybe, the complaining wasn't the issue, maybe that player just didn't know how to play symmetra, anyway, contrast that with different team of randoms, same map on defence, someone chooses symmetra but no one complains about it and we win. Some people seem to have some kind of aversion to specific heros, if they see someone with that hero, they get upset. symmetra, torb and hanzo usually.

Comment: @DCShannon I've beaten other teams only to find that one of the players on the other team was complaining about their hero choices, insulting and distracting them in team chat, and chipping away at their confidence. However, when someone on your team starts causing trouble it can have the opposite effect. A few times I've encountered individuals who insulted the whole teams abilities, and the result was that things changed for the better, they made us angry, but instead of fighting amongst ourselves we fought harder against our opponents and won

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: **Play Lucio.**

Longer answer:

Among all your requirements, the important one is at least one healer and at least one tank. Offensive heroes are better at damaging the other team than non-offensive heroes, but it's a role that other hero types can cover. No offensive heroes might seem bad, but if you have a Junkrat, Torbjorn, and Bastion, for instance, that might be all the DPS you need.

A tank is more important. Tanks absorb big hits and focus fire that smaller heroes simply can't. Still, with enough healing, and a grouped-up enough team, you can often hold an area acceptably well without a tank.

A healer is vital. Yes, there are healing packs around the map which can and should be used, but you generally have to leave combat to do this, and there often aren't enough near an objective to heal everyone.

So, if you have to fill all the roles of damage-dealer, tank, and healer, you need to focus on healing, while still having some durability, and also the ability to do damage.

That's Lucio.

Comment: I agree with this. Lucio is the safest and most versatile of picks, and he's just as useful on Payload as in CP maps, both on Attack and Def.

Answer (score 10):

I understand what you're asking about, but I don't feel there's a good "solid" answer here. One of the bigger issues with with Ranked play is that **you** alone cannot make **others** change, no-more then you can tell someone else to "play better" and have them magically improve.

I would start with the following suggestions though to help improve your game and team chances:

1. First and foremost: *Make sure you're comfortable before to play Ranked*.

   Do whatever you need to do before logging in, eat well, refresh, shower if you want to. Compared to Quick Play, Ranked Play is stressful and any little annoyance is going to snowball. There might be days where you just can't even play due to too many factors in your way. Personally, I'll play Quick Play and see if I'm tunnel visioning too often as a way to determine if I'm OK for Ranked that day. If I do poorly in Quick, then imagine how much worse I'll preform when stressed out?
2. Say Hi, in *text and voice*.

   As soon as I'm in game, I'll type "hiya" but also make sure I'm joined into the in-game team chat. I've found that most people will not talk unless they feel there's a second person on the mic as well. Just saying something should get people talking, which leads to more useful information when call-outs (reaper behind team, Mercy is down, Ult ready) are announced.  The Comms Wheel in game is useless if no-one understands what you're saving your ult for.
3. Talk to your teammates like people, *not like children*.

   I've been in games where I'm playing with people who where on the enemy team before. Win or lose, I know that they know how to play and I would hope that they have the same thought of me.  When talking to someone, do not flame them or call them names since it's only going to have a adverse affect on your own team. (ie, If you try to say "gg ez" to the enemy team, they're very likely going to have a second wind to make you eat your words. If you tell your own teammate to "stop sucking", it's only going to cause them to not listen to you when you warn of that sneaky reaper.) If you show some respect, is most cases people will respect you back.
4. Be the change *you* want to see.

   Is the team missing a Tank? then fill that role. Healer? Fill that role. Is the Team going to do a bastion/Reign combo? Figure out with them how to make it work. Not every team will be comprised of all-stars, but the winning team is the one that works together, even if that means breaking meta or trying out something unusual.  That might not be a game where you can play your best character, but the change-up might be unorthodox enough to work.
5. Finally, there's some games you can't win, and there's some people you can't work with.

   At the end of the day, Ranked is 12 people in one match with enough random variables that might have determined the winner before the game started. Much like the leavers in your own game, you can't control for every scenario.  The least you can do is to be kind enough for "gg", and select "block user" ONLY for the most toxic of players.

As of this post, I'm floating around 2700~ with a slow climb. If I'm doing well, I'll keep playing Ranked, but quit for the day after two losses.  That's usually a good sign to come back another time when I'm feeling better and when my group pool has changed-up enough.

Comment: That's actually a pretty solid answer which also works for other competitive games. Even though I also kind of feel like most of that should be self-evident.

Comment: A ton of it does feel like "duh" points, but it's very similar to when someone asks "Where does your ideas come from?" or "How can I make a video?". There's no secret setting or switch that the pros are hiding from everyone else. I'm hoping that anyone who passes by understands the limitation in trying to "fix" others.

Comment: 1. I do as much as i can ;)
2. text yes, voice not really. I have disabled the Voice because of the fear of the typical 12-Years Old.
3. I Do, till someone says such things. Then i try to make him clear that this attitude is not ok
4. I do as much as i can but i can't fill 2 Roles. If a Tank is missing i play it, if a Healer is missing, even if i play then not very good,i play them but i can't play both at the same time
5. If a game is currently good, i will say it. if it was a game,i say it was a good game and i block not very often.
The Point i was asking was point 4:i can't play2 roles

Comment: But in the Result: I follow all these Options as much as i can, but Rule 4 has mostly the the fault that one player can't Play 2 Positions.

And i should quit when some losses came... the change of the group pool is a very good argument

Comment: Point 4 is very important. There are enough Hanzo-only players that urge other players to fill missing roles. Communicate with your team. Maybe someone just never plays a tank but would take your healer spot if you were to switch.

Comment: The problem with disabling altoghter the voice chat is that you'll miss important information about the team comp and flankers. (A genji wrecking havoc in your back line is called through voice chat. There's no time to type it out).

Comment: Avoiding 12 years old is a valid concern, but avoiding other teamates that are trying to make information flow around isn't. So you should mute people once they are negative/uninformative on a repetitive basis. It's sad to say, but you have to deal with them at least 2-3 times and if they refuse to help, block them (just like IRL)

Comment: Just to add in regards with Voice, muting people in game is easier then turning the voice option back on in settings. My experience in quick (where I don't have the same quality control as in Ranked) hasn't been that bad where I needed to voice-mute someone yet. (I have a decent sized block list though due to what people -typed- out though.)

Comment: I Will mark this as the Answer, but it don't really answer my question. I think this Question instead should be deleted because the pure anger mob of this question.

Comment: These are good points, but don't really address the meat of the question, which is what to do when there are multiple roles that need filled. You can't fill all of them. I play Tank or Support 80% of the time, but I can't play both. I usually play Lucio if I have to try to do both.

Comment: I somewhat agree with you @DCShannon but it's a flawed question to start with. I'm looking at this from the perspective of the post where the player feels like no-one is listening to them. Much like the adage of "*If you think everyone is a jerk, maybe you're the jerk*", being in the right frame of mind (and taking steps to reduce the hostility on your team) will greatly affect your own performance and that of your teammates.

Comment: @NBN-Alex That's fair. This can be a pretty serious problem even if you're super polite all the time, though. I added another answer to attempt to cover that case.

Answer (score -2):

There isn't much you can do, apart from reporting them.

1. Best you can do is try your best to change your current pick to suit the team needs.
   I've played many competitive games with just one Healer or 1 Tank and we've managed to win.
2. You can try to pursued them to change hero. **Never yell, threaten or curse at them.** People are much more likely to listen to you and swap heroes if you ask nicely and present the evidence, you get slaughtered and don't make progress on the objective.
3. If someone leaves try to encourage your teammates to still try and do their best.

> mostly i chooses my Character as first or second so i must go back to the base and switch them

There's plenty of time to switch characters if you see the team comp is not perfect. Don't insta-pick Genji and run along doing your solo game. This game is team-based. Wait for the last second your team is spawned (On defence) and pick your hero accordingly. Check the team with Tab on offence and switch should your team require a certain hero.

Comment: I don't really insta-pick but i pick mostly Characters Like Junkrat, Reinhardt or D.Va which are not so much a Position which should change. A Genji or one of the 3 Snipers: Yes they can and should sometimes Change(Widow and Hanzo for Attack is not such a good option in my opinion ;))

Comment: I'm hesitant to agree that reporting someone should be a factor in this situation. There are plenty of other situations where reporting is a good thing to do, but reporting someone who doesn't pick for the team play is not a valid reason to report someone. If they're openly toxic, insulting, or cheating, then sure, but that's a different question entirely.